# Android - Nested scroll view with Dynamic view pager not rendering the Ui in release mode but its working in debug mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I am using DynamicViewPager with Nested scroll view

Problem here all the ui elements inside nested scroll view working fine in debug mode but when it comes to release mode ui is not rendering at all

i got the one solution to fix is using "fillviewport = true" , but the question is why this issue not appeared in debug mode.

Here is my XML code

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/wild_sand"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DynamicHeightViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slot_date_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/wild_sand" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/cc_near_by_location"
        layout="@layout/click_collect_near_by_locations" />

</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

Dynamic View Pager

```
public class DynamicHeightViewPager extends ViewPager {

public DynamicHeightViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initPageChangeListener();
}

public DynamicHeightViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPageChangeListener();
}


private void initPageChangeListener() {
    addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            requestLayout();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    View child = getCurrentView(this);
    if (child != null) {
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}


View getCurrentView(ViewPager viewPager) {
    try {
        final int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
            final ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams)
                    child.getLayoutParams();

            Field f = layoutParams.getClass().getDeclaredField("position");
            //NoSuchFieldException
            f.setAccessible(true);
            int position = (Integer) f.get(layoutParams);

            if (!layoutParams.isDecor && currentItem == position) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}